# Mandatory Flush for a repository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Situation: JPA, SpringBoot, Hibernate

```
public interface ViewRepository
        extends JpaRepository<SomeView, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SomeView> {

    Optional<SomeView> findByIdAndLanguageId(Long id,Long lid);
}
```

```
//service
SomeView getSomeView(){
SomeView someView1 = repo.findByIdAndLanguageId(id,lid1);
....
//now get in it in different lang id
SomeView someView2 = repo.findByIdAndLanguageId(id,lid2);

//the problem here is that the value for someView2is the same as someView1 since hibernate cash this.
}
```

Is there an annotation / way to prevent this caching for any call to this repository only?(not application wide turning of the caching) at service level or repository level ....

Comment: Can you share your `SomeView` entity? I think you have a structural problem here, I think your problem is not cache related.

Comment: Hibernate logging has to be also enabled in hibernate configuration.

Add lines

hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true. And see the queries getting printed on the logger / console.

Comment: I did enable the logger and yes the correct sql query is being run! 
@İsmail Y it is a simple view mapped to an entity

Answer (score 1):

This is main feature of Hibernate.

If you look something up and change new found entity, changes will be saved to database without any additional code.

If you don't want that you need to use thing called "stateless session". But please warn everyone around about it, because otherwise you end up with many surprised people. This "stateless session" isn't very popular thing and no one will expect you use it.

Comment: how do i use it in my example and where to declare it ,... since it is a mysql view it is not ment to save anyway and is read only

Comment: You really shouldn't use this unless you really know why you're doing it. If you need someView1 and someView2 to be different instances just use a copy constructor or some kind of cloning mechanism

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want this caching to happen, you can immediately detach the entity after reading it i.e.:

```
SomeView someView1 = repo.findByIdAndLanguageId(id,lid1);
entityManager.detach(someView1);
```